# Unable to send payload data to the backend in Axios Express

Tags: node.js, express, axios, fetch-api

I have tried the to send data from my react application to my node server using axios but I the data at the backend is undefined
This is my code at the server where I want to log the data sent to the server

```
router.post("/register",(req,res) => {
console.log(req.query)
}
```

This is my axios code which is triggered onSubmit

```
onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newUser = {
        name : this.state.name,
        email : this.state.email,
        password : this.state.password,
        password2 : this.state.password2
    };
    console.log(newUser);
    axios.post("/api/users/register",{
        headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        params : newUser
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

At the backend in the terminal I get empty set of curly braces

Comment: can you post `this.state` obj before it is sent to back? also have you tried `req.body` instead of `query`?

Comment: Use `body` to send your data to the backend

Answer (score 1):

Post requests are received over `req.body`

POST: `req.body`

GET: `req.query` or `req.params`

- Example `req.query`

  ```
  /register?user=1234
  ```

  Server side:

  ```
  router.get("/register", ...);   

  req.query.user // 1234
  ```
- Example `req.params`

  ```
  /register/1234
  ```

  Server side:

  ```
  router.get("/register/:user", ...);

  req.params.user // 1234
  ```

You also need an middleware for POST that parses your incoming body.

```
app.use(express.json());
```